# uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null at frame

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im making a loading bar.

And now i got an error when i click on download

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

I dont know what i am dong wrong please can someone help me here is my code

```
<a class="tooltip-test" id="header"><div class="progress" id="headerTop" style="cursor:default">
                <div id="myElement" class="progress-bar bg-info progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated myBar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%">
                    <p class="text-center">0%</p>
                </div>
            </div></a>
            <button onclick="move()" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg">download</button>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function move() {
                document.getElementById("headerTop").style.cursor = "wait";
                var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
                var width = 0;
                var id = setInterval(frame, 1000);
                function frame() {
                    if (width >= 99) {
                        var number = random(99, 100)
                        if(number = 99) {
                            clearInterval(id);
                            document.getElementById("MyElement").className =
                            document.getElementById("MyElement").className.replace
                            ( /(?:^|\s)bg-info(?!\S)/g , 'bg-danger' )
                            document.getElementById("header").title = "Oops looks like something has gone wrong reload the page to start over";
                        }else if (number = 100) {
                            clearInterval(id);
                            document.getElementById("MyElement").className =
                            document.getElementById("MyElement").className.replace
                            ( /(?:^|\s)bg-info(?!\S)/g , 'bg-success' )
                            document.getElementById("header").title = "download is ready";
                        }
                    } else {
                        width++;
                        elem.style.width = width + '%';
                        elem.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
                    }
                }
            }
    </script>
```

F.Y.I i am using bootstrap for the styling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Jonathan's correction, another issue might be that *elem*, *width* and *id* are defined in the parent move() function, and not in the child frame() function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function move() {
                document.getElementById("headerTop").style.cursor = "wait";
                function frame() {
                    var elem = document.getElementById("myElement");
                    var width = 0;
                    var id = setInterval(frame, 1000);
                    if (width >= 99) {
                        var number = random(99, 100)
                        if(number = 99) {
                            clearInterval(id);
                            document.getElementById("myElement").className =
                            document.getElementById("myElement").className.replace
                            ( /(?:^|\s)bg-info(?!\S)/g , 'bg-danger' )
                            document.getElementById("header").title = "Oops looks like something has gone wrong reload the page to start over";
                        }else if (number = 100) {
                            clearInterval(id);
                            document.getElementById("myElement").className =
                            document.getElementById("myElement").className.replace
                            ( /(?:^|\s)bg-info(?!\S)/g , 'bg-success' )
                            document.getElementById("header").title = "download is ready";
                        }
                    } else {
                        width++;
                        elem.style.width = width + '%';
                        elem.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
                    }
                }
            }
    </script>
```

Comment: i tried it without the frame function but it stil gave me the error

Comment: i think the proble is here: } else {
                        width++;
                        elem.style.width = width + '%';
                        elem.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
                    }

Comment: after i placed your code in my code it got rid off the error only problem now is that the progres bar nothing does it just keeps standing still

Comment: I made a later edit to my example replacing instances of "MyElement" with "myElement".

Comment: well i give up it's stil not working and this isn't important, it's just getting my skil up with javascript. i flag yours as helped because u're answer got me the furthest

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is with this line:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
```

You're selecting by Id but myBar is a class

So you should select by classname

You could also just select by id as you do below:

```
var elem document.getElementById("MyElement");
```

That's probably the easiest thing to do.

Comment: I will try that later i need to eat now

Comment: stil get the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at frame

Answer (score 0):

**Observation :** There is no `id` with name `myBar` is available in your `DOM`.

**Statement :** `var elem = document.getElementById("myBar")` will return null.

Hence, you are getting below error as you are trying to access `style` property of `null`.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null